# ELK query specifying a list of names to return all records with names matching the names in the list

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When I build an ELK query and specify the criteria like:

```
'query_string' : {
    'query': 'product.name: "' + productName + '"'
               + ' AND cost: xxxx'
    }
}
```

It returns the records with product.name matching the value in variable productName but if I want to specify a list of productNames[], and all records containing product name from that list need to be returned, how do I modify the query above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `product.name:(productA OR productB OR productC)`. Check out the [query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) docs.

If you don't need to use a `query_string` query, you could also use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with a [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "product.name": ["productA", "productB", "productC", ...]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "cost": "xxxx"
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "otherField": "yyyy"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this is more like putting the values here. The number of items in the list is a not fixed. It can vary and its there in an array variable. Do I have to build a string from the list/aray of items I have to create the above format and put that string here like you here as product.name:strvariable? If yes, Is there no better option?

Comment: If you don't need to use a query_string query, you could use a [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html). (You can use a bool query to combine them.)

Comment: dshockley, I was just now trying what you suggested and I need additional conditions and not just cost, lets say 'type'. Can I specify the two conditions in match here?

Comment: @user1892775 Yes, you can add as many clauses as you want (up to 1024 by default, but this is configurable). I updated the example to show another `match` clause, but you can use any type query (including another `bool` query). See [the query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html).

Comment: dshockley, I had eventually used the query_string style the way you provided and that worked for my case